# is there q difference between a public variable and getThatvariable function refresh?

Tags: solidity, remix

We know that we can either use a getVarible return function, or simply use a public scope for that variable, however is there a major difference besides of when we wants that state variable to not be a public one and then use a get function?

I'm asking this because when trying to just use a public variable (not of type address), I only get the initial variable value, although the a getVariable works just fine.

```
    uint public userBlance = address(this).balance ;

function getBalance() public view returns (uint){
    uint balance = address(this).balance;
    return balance;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no different at all. But your code is a bit ambigous.

Let's say your initial balance is 10.

`userBalance = address(this).balance`

Then you update the balance to 20.

`address(this).balance = 20`

The problem is `userBalance` doesnt update, because it points to the adress of 10, instead of the address of the balance.

While the function getBalance access the address of user again for the balance.

---

This is not the solidity stuff but it the same with other language.

`userBalance` point to the value (10) instead of the reference, hence it does not change. Unless you modify the userBalance along with statement `address(this).balance = 20`